# How to autopopulate dialogue list in lotus notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

I am having 1 form with 3 fields.
1st field is country,2nd field is state and 3rd field is city.
I configured the values for this fields from other form.
The problem is when i select country it has to display states come under that country and same like for city also.when i select a state it has to display the cities come under that state only.

Answer (score 0):

You need resource documents, where you get the values of states and cities from. Either make a document for each country (containing the states) and for each state (containing the cities) or make only one document containing the states and cities in seperate fields.

Depending on the key (the country selected in your country field) use @DbLookup in your selection formula of the dialogue fields to find the right document/field (depending on which method you use).

Answer (score 0):

In the properties for your Country and State fields, you need to make sure that you have the "Refresh fields on keyword change" property checked. And on the State and City fields, you need to make sure that you have the "Refresh choices on document refresh" proprety checked.

Then you will need a mechanism to do the lookups.The best way is as described by @Lesic's answer. I.e., you e view called "(LookupStates)" where the key column is Country, and a view called "(LookupCities)" where the key column is Country+State. You will pre-populate these views with documents containing the Country, State and City fields. And on your form, the formula for choices in the State field will do an @DbLookup call to the (LookupStates) view and the formula for choices in the City field with do an @DbLookup call to the (LookupCities) field.

Note that both of the formulas have to guard against error cases as well. I.e., the formula for State choices needs to check to make sure that Country is not blank, and the formula for the City choices needs to make sure that Country and State are not blank.